# Show/Hide div if all radios are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, radio-button

I have N groups of radios. I would like to show a div if all groups of radios are checked and if not all are checked, show another div:

http://jsfiddle.net/zoLwdqx6/

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="period" value="1" />1 Year
    <input type="radio" name="period" value="2" />2 Years
    <input type="radio" name="period" value="3" />3 Years
</p>
<br>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="year" value="1" />2015
    <input type="radio" name="year" value="2" />2014
    <input type="radio" name="year" value="3" />2013
</p>
<br>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="student" value="1" />Paul
    <input type="radio" name="student" value="2" />Mary
    <input type="radio" name="student" value="3" />Jane
</p>
<br>
<div class="notchecked">[not all checkboxes are selected yet]</div>
<div class="yeschecked">[submit button]</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.yeschecked').hide();
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
    $('.yeschecked').show();
});
```

Comment: `checkbox`, I don't see any checkbox in the code

Comment: My mistake. Did radio but wrote checkbox. Fixed.

Comment: Do you really want to have all radiobuttons checked?

Comment: ^ one check per group, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where `3` is not hardcoded:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".yeschecked").hide();
  // count number of radio buttons grouped by name
  var radioGroups = [];
  $("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    if ($.inArray(this.name, radioGroups) >= 0) {
      return;
    }
    radioGroups.push(this.name);
  });
  // radioGroups = ["period", "year", "student"]
  $("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
    var all = $("input[type=radio]:checked").length === radioGroups.length;
    // using http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display
    $(".yeschecked").toggle(all);
    $(".notchecked").toggle(all === false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input type="radio" name="period" value="1">1 Year
  <input type="radio" name="period" value="2">2 Years
  <input type="radio" name="period" value="3">3 Years
</p>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="year" value="1">2015
  <input type="radio" name="year" value="2">2014
  <input type="radio" name="year" value="3">2013
</p>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="student" value="1">Paul
  <input type="radio" name="student" value="2">Mary
  <input type="radio" name="student" value="3">Jane
</p>
<div class="notchecked">[not all checkboxes are selected yet]</div>
<div class="yeschecked">[submit button]</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the checked radio button count if it is three then all categrories are selected

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zoLwdqx6/1/)

```
$('.yeschecked').hide();
$('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').length == 3) {
        $('.yeschecked').show();
        $('.notchecked').hide();
    } else {
        $('.notchecked').show();
        $('.yeschecked').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: he said that he has got n blocks of checkboxes, this checks only 3 checked boxes

Comment: He has radio buttons I could not see check boxes and radio button have exclusive selection

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by `length`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var  total =  totalChecked  = 0;
 $('input[type=radio]').on("change",function(){
        totalChecked =   $('input[type=radio]:checked').length;
       if( totalChecked  == 3  ){
           $('.yeschecked').show();
          $('. notchecked').hide();
      } else {
        $('. notchecked').show();
        $('.yeschecked').hide();
      }
 })
});
```

> for length refer **[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/string_length.htm)**

### [Here is a fiddle to the example](https://jsfiddle.net/5g7d53ab/)

Comment: In your example total will be 9 and totalChecked could be 3 at most. No way 3==9.

Answer (score 0):

As a group only one radio will be selected, so here only 3 radios will be checked.

```js
var totl; // track total radio groups
$(function() {
  var rdos = $('input[type=radio]');
  rdos.on('change', toggleDivs);
  var tmp = [], nm;
  rdos.each(function() {
    nm = this.name.toLowerCase();
    if (-1 === $.inArray(nm, tmp)) //not found in array
      tmp.push(nm); // new group
  });
  totl = tmp.length; // get count of radio groups
  toggleDivs(); //page load trigger
});

var toggleDivs = function() {
  var chkd = $('input[type=radio]:checked').length;
  $('div.notchecked').toggle(chkd !== totl);
  $('div.yeschecked').toggle(chkd === totl);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="period" value="1" />1 Year
  <input type="radio" name="period" value="2" />2 Years
  <input type="radio" name="period" value="3" />3 Years
</p>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="year" value="1" />2015
  <input type="radio" name="year" value="2" />2014
  <input type="radio" name="year" value="3" />2013
</p>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="student" value="1" />Paul
  <input type="radio" name="student" value="2" />Mary
  <input type="radio" name="Student" value="3" />Jane
</p>
<div class="notchecked">[not all checkboxes are selected yet]</div>
<div class="yeschecked">[submit button]</div>
```